# Can up-welling water at oceanic fronts be physically felt?

Tags: ocean, oceanography, ocean-currents

If you were swimming/floating within a body of water experiencing upwelling due to sea-surface thermal fronts, would you be able to physically feel the water that is being up-welled or is it on a different scale not sensed by humans?

Comment: Definitely yes! The temperature difference can be 5 degrees C in some cases

Comment: Interesting. I meant more in terms of physically feeling the water-upwelling along a front, rather than sensing temperature differences between 2 water bodies.

Comment: The upwelling velocities are tiny in general. You will not feel them. There are only a few upward motions in the ocean that can be felt like a tidal bore: http://staff.civil.uq.edu.au/h.chanson/mascaret.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a sea-surface thermal front at the northwest tip of Scotland. On the western side is water from the Gulf Stream Drift - cool, but sufficiently comfortable to swim in. On the north side is Arctic water which is horribly cold and which nobody in their right mind would swim in. I write from personal experience!

Comment: Interesting. I guess i meant more in terms of physically sensing the movement of water, rather than the temperature difference between the 2 bodies. If you were around the thermal boundary in NW Scotland, would you be able to feel a current of water upwelling to the surface?